# Selecting and displaying the count of rows with the same value in a table

Tags: mysql, count, html-table, rows

Basically this is a survey system and I want to count the Yes's and No's from my results table which has

```
  | q1  | q2  | q3 | q4 | q5 | q6  | q7 | q8  | q9  | q10 |

  | Yes | Yes | No | No | No | Yes | No | Yes | Yes | No  |

  | No | Yes | No | Yes | Yes | Yes | No | No  | Yes | No |

  | Yes | Yes | No | No | No | Yes | No | Yes | Yes | No  |

  | No | Yes | No | Yes | Yes | Yes | No | No  | Yes | No |
```

---

For example I want my result to be q1 = 2 No's 2 Yes and q2 = 4 yes 0 No's and so on
Then after that I was hoping to display it in a simple table but I'm still clueless about the query

---

```
<body>

<form method="POST">


    <table border="1">

            <th>Answered Yes</th>
            <th>Answered No</th>
        </tr>

        <?php
        include("testdb.php");
        $result= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM results");

        if($result){

        ?>


    </table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use boolean expressions:

```
select ((q1 = 'Yes') + (q2 = 'Yes') + . . .  + (q10 = 'Yes')) as numYes
```

MySQL treats a conditional expression as a number in a numeric context, with 1 for true and 0 for false.

Comment: @pinoy, their answers are correct, in the php part just do `if ($result = mysqli->query("PUT THEIR QUERIES HERE")) { print_r($result); }`, it will give you the structure of the fetched result :)

Comment: sir I think im not doing something right its not working for me

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL (only) `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`, so summing a condition *counts* how many times it's true:

```
select
    sum((q1 = 'Yes') + (q2 = 'Yes') + ... etc) yeses,
    sum((q1 = 'No') + (q2 = 'No') + ... etc) nod
from mytable
```

Comment: How about the No's?

Comment: Ok thanks but sir how will I be able to display the counts of Yes and No using fetch array? @bohemian

Comment: @pinoy what do you mean exactly? Do you need 2 rows, 1 for yes and 1 for no?

Comment: Yes sir basically showing how many people did yes and no like the example above for q1 it had 2 yes and 2 no. @Bohemian

Comment: @pinoy try it now

Comment: Sir how will i display this to test? :( please be patient with me @bohemian

Comment: @pinoy I don't do PHP, but something like `while ($result.next()) { print("<tr><td>$result.get(1)</td><td>$result.get(2)</td></tr>") }` would be my guess.