# Count and display same value but different entry

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Basically this is a survey system and I want to count the Yes's and No's from my results table which has

```
  | q1  | q2  | q3 | q4 | q5 | q6  | q7 | q8  | q9  | q10 |

  | Yes | Yes | No | No | No | Yes | No | Yes | Yes | No  |

  | No | Yes | No | Yes | Yes | Yes | No | No  | Yes | No |

  | Yes | Yes | No | No | No | Yes | No | Yes | Yes | No  |

  | No | Yes | No | Yes | Yes | Yes | No | No  | Yes | No |
```

---

For example I want my result to be q1 = 2 No's 2 Yes and q2 = 4 yes 0 No's and so on
Then after that I was hoping to display it in a simple table but I'm still clueless about the query

---

```
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Answered Yes</th>
                <th>Answered No</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            include("testdb.php");
            $result= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM results");
            if($result){
            ?>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting and displaying the count of rows with the same value in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41538841/selecting-and-displaying-the-count-of-rows-with-the-same-value-in-a-table)

Comment: Yes but I typed the wrong info there and I was worried that no one would be able to read the edited part :/

Comment: . . The answer would appear to be the same.

Comment: I'm still not able to digest the line of query you answered can you please explain it to me? sorry kind of noob here

Comment: See normalisation. A database table is not a spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql query

```
SELECT 
(SELECT count(q1) FROM questions WHERE q1 = 'yes') AS q1y,
(SELECT count(q1) FROM questions WHERE q1 = 'no') AS q1n,
(SELECT count(q2) FROM questions WHERE q2 = 'yes') AS q2y,
(SELECT count(q2) FROM questions WHERE q2 = 'no') AS q2n
FROM questions
LIMIT 0,1;
```

And for your code

```
    <body>

    <form method="POST">


        <table border="1">

                <th>Answered Yes</th>
                <th>Answered No</th>
            </tr>

            <?php
            include("testdb.php");
            $result= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT 
    (SELECT count(q1) FROM questions WHERE q1 = 'yes') AS q1y,
    (SELECT count(q1) FROM questions WHERE q1 = 'no') AS q1n,
    (SELECT count(q2) FROM questions WHERE q2 = 'yes') AS q2y,
    (SELECT count(q2) FROM questions WHERE q2 = 'no') AS q2n
    FROM questions
    LIMIT 0,1;");

            if($result){
$obj = $result->fetch_object();
echo '<tr><td>Question 1 '.$obj->q1y.'Yes</td><td>Question 1 '.$obj->q1n.'No</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>Question 2 '.$obj->q2y.'Yes</td><td>Question 2 '.$obj->q2n.'No</td></tr>';    
            ?>


        </table>

    </body>
```

Comment: I will test this sir thank you!! I was wondering if you could also teach me how to display it like q1 = 2 Yes 2 No, q2 = 4 Yes 0 No and so on @abbas

Comment: @pinoy you can use the query recommended by shmosel. I think that query is more efficient.

Comment: Thank you so much @abbas this worked perfectly! and yeah I used shmosels query just like you said. Thanks for the time sir!

Comment: @ranger i am happy it can help. But i do not know why i got -ve vote for it :)

Comment: I clicked the acceptance check of your answer I don't know why it's doing that @abbas

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(q1 = 'Yes') AS q1yes
     , SUM(q1 = 'No') AS q1no
     , SUM(q2 = 'Yes') AS q2yes
     , SUM(q2 = 'No') AS q2no
     ...
  FROM results;
```

Comment: Sor how will I display this just to test?

Comment: @pinoy However you want.

Comment: I was planning it to display like  2 yes 2 no for Q1, 4 yes 0 No for Q2 and so on. Can you tell me how sir?

Comment: @pinoy No, not really. You asked a SQL question, which I answered. Displaying the data depends on the client and driver you're using, which I'm not very familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
 SUM(if q1 = 'Yes',1,0) AS q1yes,
 SUM(if q1 = 'No',1,0) AS q1no,
 SUM(if q2 = 'Yes',1,0) AS q2yes,
 SUM(if q2 = 'No',1,0) AS q2no
FROM questions
LIMIT 1;
```

Have you tried counting with if?

Note : using values like integer (0,1) instead of string can give more logical and faster results.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).